# Read old login histoy from Time Machine Backup

Tags: macos, terminal, user-account

How can I read the login history of the `last` command before `wtmp begins` from a Time Machine Backup before the date of `wtmp begins`?

Is there any way to do this by replacing some current files on my system with files of the backup?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer, as I don't know where the last log data is now stored.

From `man 5 wtmp`

```
FILES
     (These files no longer exist in 10.5 or later.)

     /var/run/utmp     The utmp file.
     /var/log/wtmp     The wtmp file.
     /var/log/lastlog  The lastlog file.
```

.. so you will be out of luck finding them to restore.

My first thoughts of this answer were that Linux `last` supports the `-f` flag to specify a file other than `/var/log/wtmp` but that option is not in the macOS `last`. Even so, the fact the files don't exist sort of accounts for that.

`/var/run/utmpx` and `/var/run/wtmpx` may be the modern equivalents, but may also be part of TM standard exclusions (I think `/var/run` and `/private/var/run` maybe the same thing?), so you'd need to have something like a CCC backup.

Sorry for all the speculation. May be someone else has something further to offer.